# Long title in tikzposter

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

I would like to have a long title in tikzposter and have tried to introduce a newline within the `\title{}` command using `\\` and `\newline` but it does not start a new line. In the old tikzposter class I think that long titles were split among several lines by default. I will be glad to know about any workaround for displaying long titles on several lines in the new tikzposter class.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that `tikzposter` puts the title inside a `\scalebox` thus preventing line breaks. You can recover line breaking placing your title inside a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering This is a really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  long title for a poster}}
\institute{The Institute}
\author{The Author}
\titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
\column{0.7}
\block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
\note{Notetext}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To have long title in `\documentclass{tikzposter}` I used `minipage` environment to get centred (`\centering`) title with a line break (`\\`), larger vertical space between the lines (`\bigskip`) and second line of the title on one line (`\mbox`).

```
\title{
 \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \centering
   First part of the title quite long:
   \\
   \bigskip
   \mbox{second part of the title much much longer than the first}
 \end{minipage}
}
```

I used the above together with:

```
\maketitle[width=0.95\textwidth]
```

(I'm not completely sure how width of `minipage` relates to `\maketitle` `width` but it works well.)

Comment: I used the width parameter in the `maketitle` command to make the title box wider, which is what I was looking for.