# How can I make my title wrap in a tikzposter

Tags: line-breaking, titles, tikzposter

I'm making a poster using the tikzposter document class, it's working nicely except that my title is too long and I can't make it wrap, I've tried `\\`, `\protect`, `\newline` and `\par`. `\\` and `\par` throw errors and `\newline` does nothing.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=10mm, innermargin=15mm, lockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\title{Making posters with really long titles: The hassles of using \LaTeX when I could be doing it in some WYSIWYG editor instead.}
\author{frogamic}
\institute{University}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \block{Intro}{Intro stuff}
  \begin{columns}
   \column{0.5}
      \block{Method}{Method stuff}
    \column{0.5}
      \block {Results}{Results stuff}
  \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Put this in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{\scalebox{\TP@titletextscale}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\centering
#1
\par
\vspace{0.5em}
\end{minipage}%
}}}
\makeatother
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=10mm, innermargin=15mm, lockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

\makeatletter
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{\scalebox{\TP@titletextscale}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\centering
#1
\par
\vspace{0.5em}
\end{minipage}%
}}}
\makeatother

\title{Making posters with really long titles: The hassles of using \LaTeX{} when I could be doing it in some WYSIWYG editor instead.}
\author{frogamic}
\institute{University}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \block{Intro}{Intro stuff}
  \begin{columns}
   \column{0.5}
      \block{Method}{Method stuff}
    \column{0.5}
      \block {Results}{Results stuff}
  \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As per this identical question: [Long title in tikzposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179983/long-title-in-tikzposter?rq=1)

I solved it by putting the title in a `\parbox`:

```
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Making posters with really long titles: The hassles of using LaTeX when I could be doing it in some WYSIWYG editor instead.}}}
```