# Idiomatic TikZ based poster class

Tags: tikz-pgf, posters, tikzposter

I would like to create conference posters using idiomatic TikZ code as far as possible.
I took a look at `tikzposter` ([CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter?lang=en)) but it seems rather unmaintained.
The documentation was last updated in January 2014.

To make things precise, I am missing e.g. this:

- Predefined coordinates like `page.north east`.
- Multi-row titles without [hacks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180234/how-can-i-make-my-title-wrap-in-a-tikzposter).
- Less `vbox`, `hbox`, ... in the [source code](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzposter/tikzposter.dtx).
- Support any number of font sizes.

Should I rewrite `tikzposter` or is there something else ideally with a Github page which I can use and contribute to?

Comment: You can still use `tikzposter`. Old code does not necessarily imply bad code. Latest TikZ is from 2015. `beamerposter` is also fine-ish. If you don't like boxes TeX must be fun for you :-)

Comment: with the `remember picture, overlay` options, you can access coordinates based on the current page.

Comment: there are only 2/7 `vbox`/`hbox` in the code . If this is too much, don't ever look into the beamer source :)

Comment: Here you have several alternatives: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex/383347#383347

Comment: @Ignasi: The `tcolorbox` version you linked really looks promising.

Comment: Best not look in *its* source if you think the number of boxes @samcarter mentioned is problematic. (Why do you object to these anyway? It seems a very odd desideratum.)