# How does one split a title into two lines?

Tags: titles, tikzposter

I am using the `tikzposter` package, and I was wondering how one could split the title into two lines:

```
\documentclass[24pt, a0papper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Extreeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeemly Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Tiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiitle Here}
\author{ShareLaTeX Team}
\date{\today}
\institute{ShareLaTeX Institute}

\usetheme{Board}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: usually titles are split by making use of "\\". In the case presented \title{Extreeeemly \\ Loooong \\ Title}

Comment: Also see: [here]:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179983/long-title-in-tikzposter?rq=1

Comment: `\title{\parbox[t]{0.75\linewidth}{\centering <long title text>}}` ..?

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned in the comments, you can simply use `\\` wherever you want the line break.

If a title is used in links with the `hyperref` package (also for example when chapters have links in the table of contents), you use `\texorpdfstring{\\}{}`